Stop re-render when props is empty
I have a component that render some error/warning
function getErrorOption(errorType: string): string {
    switch (errorType) {
      case 'error_zero':
        return `zero_error`;
      case 'Error_Option_1':
        return `Some String Value`;
      case 'Error_Option_2':
        return `some string value`;
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }

export default component myComponent(...props: Props) {
  const {name, ID} = props;
  const [errorType, setErrorType] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`YOUR_API_ENDPOINT/${id}`);
        const data = response.data;
        setData(data);
        if (data.generic_dataset_exists === false) {
            // don't render anything
        } else if (data.inactive_data_upload === true) {
          // don't render anything
        } else if (
          data.total_active_items / data.total_items <
           0.5 // it can be anything.
        ) {
          setErrorType('Error_Option_1');
        } else if (
          data.total_empty_items /
            data.total_active_items >
            0.2 // doesn't matter what this is 
        ) {
            setErrorType('Error_option_2')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  const  final_error= getErrorOption(errorType);

  return final_error ? (
<SOMETINGRENDERING errortype = {final_error}> </SOMETINGRENDERING>
  ) : null;
}

This component is called from parent component using my_id
const my_id = // id comes from some state mgmt, this state is 
changed from multiple component , this is readonly access. 
{
my_id ? <MyComponent id = {my_id}/>
}

This component is called with proper id when calling for the first time and it can be null/ empty string '' when called later.
My api fetch is correct and don't need fixing only part i need fixing is how it's rendering and re-rendering and removing the the warning component.
my requirement

When for the first time component is called with proper ID (non null/ non empty/ not undefined) show the error/warning
When second time it comes with different proper ID, change the ID and fetch the data and re-render the waring
When the component is called with empty/undefined/null props (this happens only the component is called after proper ID), this re-renders the component as id is changed it should not re-render the component, or the previous warning should be rendered without any change

How should I achieve that. I know we could use usememo but can't figure it out.
If I use my_id ?  it removes the warning completely but it should not delete the warning rather show the previous warning.
I tried adding if (id !== '' && id != null) {fecth the api }, this doesn't work.

There is a pattern discussed over here as Adjusting some state when a prop changes. This might be applicable in your case.
It is all about how to adjust the state based on the props. Normally it is done through useEffect. However, it has the drawback that there will be a render with stale state. This stale render will subsequently be re-rendered by the state updaters in useEffect. The pattern above specifically addresses to avoid the stale renders.
In this pattern the state is changed during the render. Whenever the sates are changed during a render, React will throw away the JSX returned by the render, and tries for another render. By this way, the stale render as it happens while using useEffect is avoided.
A sample code is given below. You may please take advantage of the comments given in the codes.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [changedState, setChangedState] = useState(Math.random());
  return (
    <>
      <Component changedProps={changedState} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setChangedState(Math.random())}>
        Change props with a random value
      </button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setChangedState(null)}>
        Change props with a null value
      </button>
      <br />
    </>
  );
}

function Component({ changedProps }) {
  const [adjustedState, setAdjustedState] = useState(changedProps);
  const [prevProps, setPrevProps] = useState(null);

  // if there is a change in the props
  if (changedProps !== prevProps) {
    if (changedProps) {
      // When the new value is truthy
      // then set the component state to the new value
      // and initiate a new render.
      // Meantime keep track of the previos value as well.
      setPrevProps(adjustedState);
      setAdjustedState(changedProps);
    } else {
      // When the new value is falsey
      // then set the component state to the previous value
      // but cancel the previous value as well.
      setAdjustedState(prevProps);
      setPrevProps(null);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      Adjusted State value : {adjustedState}
      {console.log(`JSX for the state : ${adjustedState}`)}
    </>
  );
}

Test runs
On loading the app.
The console log shows two sets of JSX, however there is only one render happens here. The first set of JSX will be thrown away since the state has been adjusted during the first render. And there will be another render triggered immediately. This second render does not change the state during the render, therefore it will be completed rendering in the normal way.*

On clicking the button "change props with a random number"
As discussed in the first test run, there will be two sets of JSX here as well, but only one render.

On clicking the button - Change props with a null value
Everything happens as per the previous cases. Still the second render happens with the previous state value. This is visible in the console logs.

